# ReactJS: re-render not working after component's property is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a react issue and I am not seeing where the issue could be.  For the code below: I created an accordion component that will display and hide depending upon the value of a state variable called displayForm.

When someone presses a button internal to the InlineListComponent, it should make the form inside InlineListComponent appear.  I am passing the this.displayTireAccessories in the displayAction property.  I am resetting the state variable for displayForm from false to true, which I thought would then trigger the InlineListComponent to re-render since the displayForm property value has changed.  This does not seem to be the case.  I added console.log statements to displayAction and the render method for InlineListComponent.  I can see where the value is getting updated in the displayForm, however, I am not getting any console.log to print from the InlineListComponent.

What am I missing in the rules for re-rendering that would make this not work?

```
<InlineListComponent
    orientation="Vertical"
    options={[{name: 'Tires', value: '1'},
        {name: 'Rims', value: '2'},
        {name: 'Hubcaps', value: '3'}]}
    text="name"
    label="Tire accessories (you must enter at least one)"
    key="tireAccessories"
    action={async (item, e) => {
        await this.displayTireAccessories(item);
    }}
    displayAction={async (e) => {
        await this.displayTireAccessories({});
    }}
    displayForm={this.state.displayForm}>
      <TireAccessories addAccessory={this.addAccessory}/>
</InlineListComponent>

this.displayTireAccessories = async (item) => {
  const {dispatch} = this.props;
  await this.setState({displayForm: true});
}

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        displayForm: true
    }
}
```

Comment: `displayForm`  is never false. Set it to false in the constructor.

Comment: I set it to false for testing purposes.  It is regularly  true.

Comment: Ah, I guess I don't see where that value ever changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly `await` a `setState`, it doesn't return anything.
BUT you can use its callback argument to make it a promise that you can `await` :

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.setState(state, resolve)
});
```

By the way, everytime you have an async function that just awaits one promise at the end of the function, you can discard the `async await` keywords and just return the promise.

So :

```
async (e) => {
    await this.displayTireAccessories({});
}
```

becomes :

```
(e) => this.displayTireAccessories({})
```